# rails validate specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, inclusion

I have this code

I have these options and if the user select anything except 'British Columbia'
to give him error message that the province have to 'British Columbia'

I believe it will solve by using the model validation

```
<%= f.label :province ,"Province (required)"%><br>
    <%= f.select(:province, [["Select One", ""],'Alberta','British Columbia','Manitoba','New Brunswick','Newfoundland and Labrador','Nova Scotia','Northwest Territories','Nunavut','Ontario','Prince Edward Island','Quebec','Saskatchewan','Yukon'], {}) %>
```

User.rb

```
  validates :province, presence: "British Columbia"
```

Comment: I had the same problem last week. As mentioned above you've used the wrong validation type. I found this article useful. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion I hope it helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't use presence, it's the wrong validation. You should use [inclusion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion):

```
validates :province, inclusion: { in: %w[British Columbia] }
```

You realize this is a nonsensical problem, right?  What's the point of offering several alternatives in the view if the validation will only accept one?

Comment: I wrote it undefined method `British Columbia' for #<User:0x007f9ebc346978>

Comment: The point might be to add other restrictions, on: :create for example. To allow more values on updates.